# Plasma remembers window keyboard layout after program terminates

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout, plasma, plasma-5

Plasma "remembers" the keyboard layout of programs, probably by the window title, after program termination. That is, when I run the same program again the keyboard layout automatically changes to what it was before termination.

This behavior is desirable while the program is running: I do want the system to remember the keyboard layout of particular windows inside a program (identified by title) while it's running, but not after program termination.

I am using Kubuntu 18.04.2 with plasma desktop 5.12.8. My keyboard layout switching policy is "Window" (as opposed to "Global" / "Desktop" / "Application").

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, navigate to IBus preferences:  *Applications → Settings → IBus preferences*,
Then choose the *Advanced* tab and deselect the *Share the same input method among all applications* option.

[image]